# Can a Win2012 R2 domain controller be used as the AD FS host in Single Sign-On integration to Azure AD?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, entra-id

I have upgraded our Active Directory from Win2008 R2 to Win2012 R2 in preparation for an integration with Azure Active Directory.
I know the integration can be done with Win2008 R2, but I figured there will be less problems if we use the latest version of Active Directory.
Right now we only have a single on-premises domain controller, so it has the FSMO-roles, and the functional level of both the forest and the domain are upgraded to Win2012 R2.

I looked at what else is needed on-premises, and according to the prerequisites here, I'll need the Active Directory Federation Services:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj151786

"Install the AD FS role service on a Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 server."

My question is; Can I install and use Federation Services on the domain controller, or do I need to have a separate domain member server and run the AD FS there instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I install and use Federation Services on the domain controller, or do I need to have a separate domain member server and run the AD FS there instead?

You would be better off running ADFS on a seperate server. running other services on a Domain Controller leads to headaches upgrading/migrating in the future.